# multiple HABTM relationships in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end


class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end
```

Above is how I declared the relationships between my models.  In my book controller and form, I can easily create a book and associate that book with a category.  But how do I associate that book with a user on creation time?  Is there a part of rails automagic that will supposedly handle this for me or would I have to do some transactional type to update the join table to associate a book with  a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instantiate a new book like so:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @book = @current_user.books.build(params[:book])
    ...
  end
end
```

This scopes the book to `@current_user`; when you save `@book`, `@book.user_id` will be set to `@current_user.id`. How you populate `@current_user` is up to you.

Comment: I tried this, it saves the to the books table, the join table (books_categories), but no entry is made to the books_users table.  I populated the @current_user based on the session_id that I store when the user logs in.

Comment: Fixed it - to save with correct data, call @current_user.save instead of @book.save